# Count and sum specific value in the table SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to look for a way to sum a specific row in a query. I found the function "group by" can do the job but I do not understand how to use it

```
    TABLE TEAM: 
    TeamID TeamName  
      1     Apes
      2     Bird
      3     Cat
      4     Dog
      5     Eagle
      6     Fish
      7     Giraffe
      8     Hawk
      9     Insect
    ==========================
    Table RECORD: 
    Date  MATCH_A  MATCH_B  A_SCORE  B_SCORE
    2/1      2        8        2        0
    2/1      5        9        4        1
    3/1      6        4        3        3
    3/1      1        3        1        2
    4/1      1        9        1        1
    5/1      2        4        0        3 
    5/1      3        8        1        0
    6/1      7        6        1        0
    6/1      3        5        1        1
    7/1      2        9        3        2                     
    7/1      4        1        1        0
```

For example, Team 1 totally play 3 matches (MATCH A+ MATCH B). 
I  want to show how many matches do the team play and how many score do them team get for match A totally

```
  TeamID TeamName  TotalMatch
      1     Apes        3
      2     Bird        3
      3     Cat         3
      4     Dog         3 
      5     Eagle       2 
      6     Fish        2
      7     Giraffe     1
      8     Hawk        2
      9     Insect      3
==============================
   TeamID TeamName  Total_Match_A_SCORE
      1     Apes        2
      2     Bird        5
      3     Cat         2
      4     Dog         1 
      5     Eagle       4 
      6     Fish        3
      7     Giraffe     1
      8     Hawk        0
      9     Insect      0
```

But my query cannot show the value correspondingly but the query add up all the value in each row

```
SELECT TEAMID, TEAMNAME, COUNT(MATCH_A, MATCH_B) AS TotalMatch
FROM TEAM, RECORD
GROUP BY TEAMID, TEAMNAME

SELECT TEAMID, TEAMNAME, SUM(A_SCORE) AS Total_MatchA_SCORE
FROM TEAM, RECORD
GROUP BY TEAMID, TEAMNAME
```

Comment: No JOIN conditions?!?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your query is missing the where clause to connect the two tables. Please modify your query like below:

```
SELECT TEAMID, TEAMNAME, COUNT(MATCH_A, MATCH_B) AS TotalMatch
FROM TEAM, RECORD
WHERE TEAM.TEAMID=RECORD.MATCH_A OR TEAM.TEAMID=RECORD.MATCH_B
GROUP BY TEAMID, TEAMNAME

SELECT TEAMID, TEAMNAME, SUM(A_SCORE) AS Total_MatchA_SCORE
FROM TEAM, RECORD
WHERE TEAM.TEAMID=RECORD.MATCH_A OR TEAM.TEAMID=RECORD.MATCH_B
GROUP BY TEAMID, TEAMNAME
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more complicated than it looks.  First, you need to learn proper, standard `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

You need a `UNION ALL`.  If you want the values in one row, you need to do it before the `GROUP BY`:

```
select t.teamid, t.teamname, count(*) AS TotalMatch, sum(a_score) as a_score
from team t join
     ((select match_a as teamid, a_score
       from record
      ) union all
      (select match_b as teamid, 0 a_score
       from record
      )
     ) m
     on t.teamid = m.teamid
group by t.teamid, t.teamname;
```

Also note the use of table aliases and qualified column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
---TOTAL MATCHES TEAM PLAYED
Select 
     TeamID 
    ,TeamName 
    ,COUNT(1) AS TotalMatch
FROM 
    team
JOIN 
    dbo.Record ON Match_A = teamID OR Match_B = teamID 
GROUP BY 
    teamID,teamName 



--TOTAL A SCORE MATCHES 
Select 
     TeamID 
    ,TeamName 
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUM(A_Score) IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE  SUM(A_Score)
    END AS TotalMatch
FROM 
    team
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Record ON Match_A = teamID 
GROUP BY 
    teamID,teamName
ORDER BY teamName




----TOTAL B SCORE MATCHES

Select 
     TeamID 
    ,TeamName 
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUM(B_Score) IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE  SUM(B_Score)
    END AS TotalMatch
FROM 
    team
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Record ON Match_B = teamID 
GROUP BY 
    teamID,teamName
ORDER BY teamName
```

Just used joins and case to output the data that you wanted. Hope this helps.